# How to get the field returned by a method invocation

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am writing a custom SonarQube rule for java, where I want to check an object is created with an argument having a specific annotation.

the file i am testing against

```java
class MyClass {

  public void doSomething() {
    final var v = new Dto();
    new MyObject(v.value1()); // Compliant since value1 has @MyAnnotation
    new MyObject(v.value2()); // Noncompliant
  }

  public static class MyObject {

    private final String value;

    public MyObject(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

  }

  @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  public @interface MyAnnotation {
  }

  public static class Dto {

    @MyAnnotation
    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    public String value1() {
      return this.value1;
    }

    public String value2() {
      return this.value2;
    }
  }
}
```

the check

```java
public class MyObjectCheck extends IssuableSubscriptionVisitor {

  @Override
  public List<Kind> nodesToVisit() {
    return Collections.singletonList(Kind.NEW_CLASS);
  }

  @Override
  public void visitNode(Tree tree) {
    NewClassTree ctor = (NewClassTree) tree;
    if(!ctor.identifier().symbolType().name().contains("MyObject")) { //to change
      return;
    }
    if(ctor.arguments().size() == 1) {
      final ExpressionTree expressionTree = ctor.arguments().get(0);
      if(expressionTree.is(Kind.METHOD_INVOCATION)) {
        MethodInvocationTree methodInvocation = (MethodInvocationTree) expressionTree;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

from the `methodInvocation`, I can manage to call `methodSelect` to have a `MethodInvocationTree` but then I can't figure how to go to the field returned by the method.

Comment: Java is always  _pass by value_. The method does not return a field, it returns a _value_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make concession where I consider the class of the method invoked being a POJO or a java record. This way I was able to fetch the linked field and annotations :

```java
        String methodName = methodInvocationTree.symbol().name();
        final Symbol.TypeSymbol methodClass = (Symbol.TypeSymbol) methodInvocationTree.symbol().owner();
        final List<SymbolMetadata.AnnotationInstance> annotations = methodClass.lookupSymbols(methodName).iterator().next().metadata().annotations();
```